# Reconnect stomp when disconnected

Tags: websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

I am using the following code to create/subscribe to a topic and handle the messages. Sometimes the connection gets lost and the error says:

```
Whoops! The connection was lost...
```

I would like to know if there is a way to reconnect it. Is it possible in the error callback or define the whole code in a method and call it recursively in error callback ?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  ........
  ...............
      try {
            var socket = new SockJS("${createLink(uri: '/stomp')}");
            var client = Stomp.over(socket);
            client.connect({}, function () {
            client.subscribe("/topic/${userInstance?.username}",                 
            function (message) {
           ............
           ....................

              });
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + error.toString());
        }
   });
```

Comment: oh god, i need the answer too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it using failure callback and connect again. It will keep trying as long as it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using in a Polymer element:

```
ready: function() {
    this.connectWs();
},
connectWs: function() {
    this.socket = new WebSocket(this.socketUrl);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(this.socket);
    this.stompClient.debug = null;
    this.stompClient.connect({},
        function(frame) {
            // Connection OK
        }.bind(this),
        function(e) {
            console.error(e, "Reconnecting WS", this.socketUrl);
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                this.connectWs();
            }.bind(this), 2500);
        }.bind(this)
    );
},
```